# Proxy object in Chrome undefined

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, ecmascript-harmony

I wanted to experiment with the Proxy object that was introduced in EMCAScript 6
Flag chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony enabled, chrome restarted

I got the error that Proxy is not defined.
Does anybody know more about the support for proxies in Chrome?

Problem only with version Chrome/Chromium >= 39
Help somebody =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy support has been removed from Chrome'e experimental JS flag, because the current implementation is completely outdated and has various issues. You can still activate it by starting Chrome from the command line with `--js-flags="--harmony-proxies"`. For now, I cannot say when it will come back.